# Chatter Group Getting Inactive

Tags: chatter

Am new to chatter and don't know much regarding it, recently we had created a new group, however, the chattering group is getting inactive automatically. Can anyone please let know why this is happening?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Chatter groups **can be archived if there are no posts or comments for 90 days**

[Please refer the following document.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_group_archiving.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, the group is an active group of chatter messages are sent out every now and then, but it seems to get achieved and inactive in between